# Como recuperar as tabelas do banco de dados MySQL com o sistema operacional corrompido?

Tags: mysql, sistema-de-arquivos

Eu possuía um site instalado no apache com windows server 2016, deu um problema no qual o sistema fui corrompido, mas os arquivos estão la, o backup que eu tenho do banco e de uma semana atrás, só que em uma semana eu tinha mexido em muita coisa, muitas horas de trabalho, gostaria de saber de alguém de vocês o que eu posso fazer para restaurar o banco, se existe algo a fazer em relação a isso, sem ter salvado por dentro daquele sistema como que eu posso proceder, lembrando que no HD o sistema não esta iniciando só que os arquivos estão intactos. Existe um arquivo que contem as tabelas que estavam em uso no sistema? Alguém pode me sugerir alguma medida do tipo. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

você pode conectar esse hd (com o Server 2016) em outro sistema, e navegar ate raiz do wampserver - cada banco possui uma pasta no diretório  `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\data` caso seu WampServer esteja instalado na em `C:\`.

Uma vez encontrada a pasta com arquivos da sua db, você pode restaura-la em uma nova instalação do Wampserver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu, vou fazer isso que você disse, obrigado pela forca, depois eu posto o resultado, eu vou ter que fazer um backup das pastas do wamp porque preciso reinstalar o windows server 2016 no mesmo HDD, vou salvar toda a pasta, porque o site ta la tambem.

Comment: Deu certo, tive medo de zuar tudo porque sou novo nisso, mas foi tiro e queda, instalei a mesma versão do wamp e copiei todas as pastas substituindo as novas pelo backup que eu fiz da antiga, voltou a ser como era, até a senha do banco. Eu salvei a pasta inteira, inclusive com os alias que eu havia feito. Valeu Paulo.Foi a partir do que você postou que me ocorreu que estaria tudo la, achei que havia mais alguma coisa fora destas pastas... por isso estava enroscado.